# Paid parking on holiday in Czechia

Tags: czech-republic, public-holidays

I'm currently parking on a public parking space in the Czech republic which is paid during the day (monday to friday), but free on weekends.

[image]

Tomorrow is Easter monday, which is a high holiday. Is this day handled like a sunday, and parking is free, or do I need to get a ticket from 7:00 AM?

Comment: Well, I'm in Pilsen, not in Prague. The article doesn't sound like this applies to other cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no universal rule that would work across Czechia. Each town sets up its own parking system so the rules vary as well.

Just a couple of examples:

### Prague

Unless the ticket machine or the parking app explicitly says otherwise, paid parking is in force even during public holidays.

> Provozní doba zóny placeného stání (ZPS) v jednotlivých parkovacích úsecích je jednoznačně určena příslušnou dopravní značkou, respektive dodatkovou tabulkou. Není-li v doplňkově v parkovacím automatu či ve Virtuálních parkovacích hodinách uvedeno jinak, pak je ZPS v provozu i ve dnech státních svátků.

http://www.parkujvklidu.cz/provozni-doba-zps-o-statnich-svatcich/

This year, a special daily cap is applied for parking fees during the Easter holidays. This only applies to those zones that aren't in force all week.

http://www.parkujvklidu.cz/parkovani-v-zps-po-dobu-velikonocnich-svatku-2/

### Brno

Public holidays aren't taken into account at all, so even if there's a holiday on a Wednesday, you still have to pay as usual.

> Q: Platí se za parkování i ve státní svátky?
>   A: Regulace parkování a jeho platba je nastavena na období od pondělí do pátek, a to nezávisle na státních svátcích či jiných významných dnech. Pokud tedy například vánoční svátky připadají na všední den, je parkování zpoplatněno.

https://www.parkovanivbrne.cz/otazky-a-odpovedi#128

### České Budějovice

Most parking zones apply Monday-Friday, excluding public holidays. There's a special zone next to the train station that's in force even during public holidays.

https://www.c-budejovice.cz/sites/default/files/obsah/layout/sloupec-1/soubory/cenik_parkovacich_zon_04_2018_final_1.pdf (section 6)

### Pilsen

There's absolutely no mention of public holidays on the official website, so you can probably assume that you have to pay on Monday-Friday as usual.

https://www.parkingplzen.cz/cz/placene-zony/